# Are there any model analytics gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm working on allowing clients to view analytics per day, week, month, in a period of time, grouped by hours or days or months, etc... All of that is based on the `created_at` attribute.

Is there any gem out there that already does this? Something like:

```
Posts.analytics(:by => :day, :period => :this_week, :column => :created_at)
```

Would return:

```
{
'2012-06-19' => 14,
'2012-06-20' => 0, // Empty rows padding support*
'2012-06-21' => 3
}
```

I'm trying to make it from scratch but it seems like a lot of unecessary work if there's already a gem to do the job.

### **Update**

I tried to make an analytics module that gets included into all models for easy analytics generation, But it's really unreliable, Sometimed i get more days than i need, and it's really messy, Could anyone collaborate and rewrite/improve on this:

```
# Usage:
# include Analytics::Timeline
# Model.timeline(:period => :last_24_hours, :time_by => :hour)

module Analytics
  module Timeline
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval {

        def self.timeline(*filters)
          filters = filters[0]
          period  = filters[:period] || :this_week
          time_by = filters[:time_by] || :days
          date_column = filters[:date_column] || :created_at

          # Named periods conventions
          period_range = case period
            when :last_12_hours
              [Time.now-12.hours, Time.now]
            when :last_24_hours
              [Time.now-24.hours, Time.now]
            when :last_7_days
              [Time.now-7.days, Time.now]
            when :last_30_days
              [Time.now-30.days, Time.now]
            when :this_week
              [Time.now.beginning_of_week, Time.now.end_of_week]
            when :past_week
              [(Time.now - 1.week).beginning_of_week, (Time.now - 1.week).end_of_week]
            when :this_month
              [Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month]
            when :past_month
              [(Time.now-1.month).beginning_of_month, (Time.now - 1.month).end_of_month]
            when :this_year
              [Time.now.beginning_of_year, Time.now.end_of_year]
            end
          period_range = period if period.kind_of?(Array)
          period_range = [period, Time.now] if period.is_a?(String)

          # determine the SQL group method
          group_column = case time_by
            when :months
              time_suffix = "-01 00:00:00"
              records = where("#{table_name}.#{date_column} > ? AND #{table_name}.#{date_column} <= ?", period_range[0].to_date, period_range[1].to_date)
              "DATE_FORMAT(#{table_name}.#{date_column.to_s}, '%Y-%m')"
            when :days
              time_suffix = " 00:00:00"
              records = where("#{table_name}.#{date_column} > ? AND #{table_name}.#{date_column} <= ?", period_range[0].to_date, period_range[1].to_date)
              "DATE(#{table_name}.#{date_column.to_s})"
            when :hours
              time_suffix = ":00:00"
              records = where("#{table_name}.#{date_column} > ? AND #{table_name}.#{date_column} <= ?", period_range[0], period_range[1])
              "DATE_FORMAT(#{table_name}.#{date_column.to_s}, '%Y-%m-%d %H')"
            when :minutes
              time_suffix = ":00"
              records = where("#{table_name}.#{date_column} > ? AND #{table_name}.#{date_column} <= ?", period_range[0], period_range[1])
              "DATE_FORMAT(#{table_name}.#{date_column.to_s}, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')"
            end

          # Get counts per cycle
          records = records.group(group_column).select("*, count(*) AS series_count, #{group_column} AS series_time")
          series = {}

          # Generate placeholder series
          time_table = { :days => 60*60*24, :hours => 60*60, :minutes => 60, :seconds => 0 }

          if time_by == :months
            ticks = 12 * (period_range[1].year - period_range[0].year) + (period_range[1].month + 1) - period_range[0].month
          else
            ticks = (period_range[1] - period_range[0] + 1) / time_table[time_by]
          end

          ticks.to_i.times do |i|
            time = period_range[1]-i.send(time_by)
            time = case time_by
            when :minutes
              time.change(:sec => 0)
            when :hours
              time.change(:min => 0)
            when :days
              time.change(:hour => 0)
            when :months
              time.change(:day => 1, :hour => 0)
            end

            series[time.to_s(:db)] = 0
          end

          # Merge real counts with placeholder series
          to_merge = {}
          records.each do |r|
            to_merge[r.series_time.to_s+time_suffix] = r.series_count
          end

          series.merge!(to_merge)
        end

      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: At the risk of saying something obvious that you already know or doesn't apply for some reason, I'd just note that using the operational database (lots of atomic record CRUD operations) for analytics and reporting (lots of big reads, index/table scans) can quickly lead to problems with both operational and analytical performance. To me at least this explains why there aren't many robust solutions out there designed to be baked into your application - that normally wouldn't be advisable as an architectural approach.

Comment: Agree with Steve I would just write the queries by hand :)

Answer (score 2):

The ActiveRecord [statistics gem](https://github.com/acatighera/statistics) seems like it could be really useful to you.

If the statistics gem doesn't help, the [admin_data gem](https://github.com/bigbinary/admin_data) has some analytics built in. Check out [the demo](http://admin-data-demo.heroku.com/admin_data/analytics/daily/phone_number). Use of the entire admin system might be overkill but you could at least try to browse the source to mimic the analytics feature.

Comment: `statistics` seems kinda ancient and unmaintained by looking at the github page for it

Comment: `admin_data` is old now too.